# table rowspan and colspan issues

Tags: html

While looking at table structure with rowspan and colspan, I stubbled upon two instances which were interesting.

View [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hPBds/)

The first table should have three rows, but the last row stays in the second row. While I understand that this is fixed if I change the bottom rowspan to 1, instead of 2, why doesn't it work this way?

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">bottom</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The second table should have a bottom border, but does not show one. Again, I realize the bottom row and the left box would work with a rowspan of 2 for the left side, and a rowspan of 1 for the bottom row, but I was wondering why it doesn't work the way I showed in jsfiddle.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st table is malformed because all of the columns from above have rowspan > 1.  The 3rd row has no columns left in which to add a cell, but you have colspan=4.

The second table is malformed because all of the columns in the second row have rowspan > 1, hence there is no final row and no bottom border.

Comment: I understand. I wasn't thinking about how I was extending the columns to the 3rd row, and then putting a third row there as well. Thanks.